# Solutions of the complex equation: $(z+1)^3 = 36(z^*+1)$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

today in an exam a friend had this equation with complex number:
$$(z+1)^3 = 36(z^*+1)$$
where with z* I mean conjugate z; can someone solve this? 
We tried and there is probably a way to solve it doing a big system with everyterm with i = 0 and everyterm without = 0; but we think that another solution must exists; thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by "... every term with i=0 and every term without = 0..."?

Comment: Not being this an equation that can be solved with the fondamental theorem of Algebra, I could put z=x+iy and $z=x^*-iy$, do every algebric calculation, move every term in the first/second part of the equation, so that every real term must be = 0, and every "i" term must be = 0!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $z + 1 = w$, then $\overline{z} + 1 = \overline{w} + 1$ as well, and you want to solve
$$
w^3 = 36\overline{w}.
$$
Multiplying both sides by $w$, we find
$$
w^4 = 36\left|w\right|.
$$
If $w = re^{i\theta}$, then $r^4e^{i4\theta} = 36 r^2$. It follows that either $r = 0$ (in which case $w = 0$), or $r^2 = 36$, so $r = 6$, and that $4\theta = 2k\pi$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$, or $\theta = k\pi/2$. Since $e^{it}$ is periodic with period $2\pi$, you only need to consider $\theta = 0$, $\theta = \pi/2$, $\theta = \pi$, and $\theta = 3\pi/2$. You get $w = 0$, $w = 6$, $w = 6 i$, $w = -6$, $w = -6i$ as possible solutions. Checking:
\begin{align*}
0^3 &= 36\cdot 0\quad\checkmark\\
6^3&=36\cdot 6\quad\checkmark\\
(6i)^3&=36\cdot (-6i)\quad\checkmark\\
(-6)^3 &=36\cdot(-6)\quad\checkmark\\
(-6i)^3 &=36\cdot(6i)\quad\checkmark\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 5):

Let $w=z+1$ and $w=re^{i\theta}$, then you are given
\begin{align*}
w^3 & = 36\bar{w}\\
w^4 & = 36||w||^2\\
r^2e^{4i \theta} &=36
\end{align*}
Now compare real and imaginary parts.

Comment: Clear and concise.  +1

Comment: @Dr.MV thanks a lot.

Comment: Plus the trivial $w=0$ solution.

Comment: @dxiv yes of course. Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 2):

From $(z+1)^3 = 36(z^*+1)$ by applying conjugate we get $(z^*+1)^3 = 36(z+1)$ then $(z^*+1)^9 = 36^3(z+1)^3=36^4(z^* + 1)$. Therefore $z^* + 1 = 0$ or $(z^*+1)^8=36^4$. Should be easy from here. Don't forget the fact that by raising to cube we did introduce some fake solutions, so at the end you'll have to verify all of them.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that $z$ and $z^*$ can be replaced; in what cases this operation is possible? Does this replacement have a specific name? Is it a part of a theorem?

Comment: @L.Repetti See the properties of conjugate: $(a + b)^*=a^* + b^*$ and $(a  b)^*=a^* b^*$